# Inexplicable syntax error in Lua for logitech gaming software

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I've being trying this language and i keep getting random syntax errors and i cant figure out why, this is a simple recoil script. It keeps telling me i have a syntax error on line 39, everything is green so i can still try it out while i try to fix. I can post the rest of the code if someone needs.

Code:

```
function recoil_values()
    if gun_mode = "gun1" then
        if round = "attack" then
            --Ash R4C-- 
            x_recoil = -1
            y_recoil = 4
            sleep_value = 10
        else
            --Twitch F2--
            x_recoil = -10
            y_recoil = 0
            sleep_value = 10            
        end
    else
        if round = "attack" then
            --Jager 41C--   
            x_recoil = 10
            y_recoil = 0
            sleep_value = 10
        else
            --Bandit MP7--
            x_recoil = 0
            y_recoil = 10
            sleep_value = 10    
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Just use two equal signs (condition) instead of one (defining) between your ```if ... then```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statements contain `=`, which is used for [assignment](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.3). Lua does not allow assignments between `if` and `then`.

If you want to compare two values for [equality](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.4), use `==`.